# Does django need to set TEST_RUNNER first to run doctest?

Tags: python, django, testing, doctest, test-runner

I started a deadly simple django project to try django's doctest:

```
# models.py
"""
>>> 1+1 == 2
True
"""
```

and run `python manage.py test` get:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Same as running `python manage.py play`.

I fixed this by setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'django_nose',
)
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-doctest']
```

My question is that whether my setting is needed or not? Cause it's not mentioned in the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/

My django version is 1.7, is it the difference between 1.4 and 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 1.6, doctests are no longer automatically discovered by Django. You'll find more on how to integrate doctests in the [1.6 release documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner).

Comment: Could you have a more detailed explanation about how django gets the doctests before?

Comment: You'll find that in the [Django 1.5 doctest documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/doctests/).